# SwiftのAVAudioPlayer でサーバーから音声ファイル（3gp）をダウンロードした後に再生したいがエラーとなる

Tags: swift

下記の環境、ソースコードでAVAudioPlayerのイニシャライザでエラーが発生します。
よろしくお願いします。

#### 環境

- Xcode 7.3
- Swift 2.2
- iPhone 5(実機)

#### エラー内容

```
Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"
```

#### ソースコード

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate,AVAudioPlayerDelegate {
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
            do{
                audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: location)
                audioPlayer.delegate = self
                audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                audioPlayer.play()
            } catch let error as NSError{
                print(error)
            }
    }
}
```

---

追記

#### 状況

- サーバーから音声ファイルをダウンロードすることには成功している
- ダウンロードされたものは”hoge.tmp”というように拡張子が”tmp”である
- ダウンロードするときに指定するURLは”https://server/hoge.3gp”のように拡張子が”3gp”である
- シミュレータではエラーにならず意図通り動作する（音声が再生される）
  *ただし、このソースコードの前画面で`audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()`（ここでいう`audioPlayer`は前画面のグローバル変数）を実行した場合に限る。（これを実行しないと音声は再生されない*

---

追記その2

シミュレータでの動作の詳細。
*シミュレータでもエラーになる場合とならない場合がある*

```
class ViewController: UIViewController ,AVAudioPlayerDelegate{
    var audioPlayer:AVAudioPlayer!
    var audioPlayer2:AVAudioPlayer!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let URL_TEST = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("hakucyou", ofType: "mp3")!)
        let URL_TEST2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("1458897593 (5)", ofType: "3gp")!)//サーバーからDLした音声ファイル
        do{
            audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: URL_TEST, fileTypeHint:"mp3")
            audioPlayer.delegate = self
            //audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
            audioPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: URL_TEST2)
            audioPlayer2.prepareToPlay()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

このソースコードを実行すると`audioPlayer2 = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: URL_TEST2)`で同エラーが発生します。
ここで`//audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()`のコメントを外すとエラーとなりません。

Comment: ご自分の質問は「編集」可能だと思うので、タイトルに誤りがあると思われたら、編集して修正してみてください。記載されたエラーコードの`2003334207 `(=`0x7768743F`=`'wht?'`)は、AudioFile.h内で`kAudioFileUnspecifiedError`(`An unspecified error has occurred.` - 仕様記述のないエラーが発生しています)と定義されており、ほとんど役に立たないエラーコードです。事象が再現できるようなサンプルの3gp音声ファイルがダウンロードできるURLなどがわかるようでしたら、御記載いただけませんか。

Comment: タイトルの件ありがとうございました。変更することができました。
またこのコメントだけでもだいぶ助かりました。ありがとうございます。
また、サーバーのURLですが事情により公開することができません…申し訳ございません。代わりになるか分かりませんが本文の方に状況の説明を記載しましたのでご覧ください。

そこに書きましたようにダウンロードは成功していて（実機でも）シミュレータでは意図通り動作しますのでやはり「パスの指定が悪い」ということが濃厚かなあと思っています…

Comment: Core Audioが再生可能なファイル形式、sandbox下でのファイルアクセスなど、細部で実機／シミュレータの違いはあるので、残念ながらこちらでは追記の情報だけで原因を絞り込むことはできません。とりあえず「DLしたファイルを直接アプリに組み込んだ場合、そのファイルは実機で再生できるか」「DLしたファイルの内容を直接`AVAudioPlayer.init(contentsOfURL:)`で初期化せずに`NSData.init(contentsOfURL:)`で作成したdataを渡して`AVAudioPlayer.init(data:)`を呼んでみる」(再生できるか、できなければどこでエラーになるか、その時のエラーコード)等をチェックすれば、ある程度切り分けられるかと思います。お試しください。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。あれからの調査結果を記載します。（本文 _追記その2_）まず _シミュレータでは条件なしに動作する_ という前提条件が覆りました。具体的には本文 _追記その2_ にある様に別インスタンスの`prepareToPlay()`を実行していれば動作する、が正しい動作でした。（この動作は正直理解できませんが…）
また…
_DLしたファイルを直接アプリに組み込んだ場合、そのファイルは実機で再生できるか_
ですがダウンロードした場合と同じ様になり、そこに差異はなさそうということを確認しました。
また…
_`A‌​VAudioPlayer.init(data:)`を呼んでみる_
ですがこちらも同箇所（イニシャライザ（`A‌​VAudioPlayer.init(data:)`））で同じ様にエラーが発生しました。
最後に…
問題となっている3gpファイルを下記に置きました
[DL](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5XEYDbB4WHYaU9JemdtbE5KMVE)

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。ファイルの方、無事ダウンロードできたようなので、こちらでもいろいろ試して、お役に立つ可能性のある情報が取れたらすぐにコメント等で連絡します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

結論から言うと、コメント中のリンクにある音声ファイルは、**現在のiOSではサポートされていない音声フォーマット**になっているようです。

DLした音声ファイルをいじって、追記その2に記述していただいた理解不能な挙動はこちらでも確認できたのですが…。

MacのQuickTime Playerでその音声ファイルを開いたところ、次のような表示がありました。
**Format: AMR Narrowband, 8000 Hz, Mono**
このAMR(Adaptive Multi-Rate)と言う音声フォーマット(3gpの音声フォーマットはAMRの他にAAC(MPEG-4)もあるようです)、現在のiOSではサポートされていないと言うことです。
[Supported Audio file formats in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1761460/supported-audio-file-formats-in-iphone)
上記記事内のリンクからも辿れるのですが、Appleの[Multimedia Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/MultimediaPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009767)では、サポートする音声フォーマットとして

- AAC (MPEG-4 Advanced Audio Coding)
- ALAC (Apple Lossless)
- HE-AAC (MPEG-4 High Efficiency AAC)
- iLBC (internet Low Bitrate Codec, another format for speech)
- IMA4 (IMA/ADPCM)
- Linear PCM (uncompressed, linear pulse-code modulation)
- MP3 (MPEG-1 audio layer 3)
- µ-law and a-law

の8種類が挙げられています。3gpの音声フォーマットがAAC(MPEG-4)であれば再生できたのだろうと思いますが、残念ながら現在のiOS(上記記事によるとiOS 4.3以降)ではAMR音声の3gpファイルは再生不可、と言うことになります。
(サポートを打ち切った後、ファイルフォーマットのチェックさえしていないので、Unsupported Formatのエラーさえ返せない、と言う状態なのだと思われます。バグと言っても良いでしょう。細部は不明ですが、iOSシミュレータの場合、一部のaudio処理はMac OS X側に丸投げするので、条件が合えば再生できてしまうのでしょう。)

と言うわけで、残念ながら、

- ファイルを再生可能な形式にコンバートして、サーバにアップロードし直す

か、または、(他社さんのリソースである等でそれができないなら)

- ダウンロードした3gp/AMRリソースをアプリが自前で再生可能な形式にコンバートする

のどちらかが必要だろうと思われます。
(残念ながらコンバータには詳しくなく、どちらの情報も持ち合わせていません。)

否定的な結果で申し訳ないのですが、こちらでわかったことをまとめると、以上のような感じです。